# Не могу установить laravel

Tags: laravel, composer

Здравствуйте

Не могу установть laravel на виртуальном сервере

Установил composer
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

Пытаюсь установить laravel

php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist

Вылетает ошибка 
[ErrorException]
  escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons

Пытался скачать с github, распоковал на сервере.  Делаю

"php composer.phar update"

Вылетает ошибка 
[ErrorException]
   proc_get_status() has been disabled for security reasons

и еще много других ошибок

Или это в composer'e проблема?
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: При чем тут композер. Видите вам пишут что некоторые функции запрещены в целях безопасности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорей всего у вас отключены эти функции хостером.
Если есть доступ в php.ini вынесите их из disable_functions если нет попросите хостера включить их. Но они врятли согласятся. Меняйте хостера.